# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): keytar.setPassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, keytar

I am trying to save a password using keytar.js, for some reason I keep getting this error when using ANY function from keytar.

For information : the lib. is installed and the functions are there and present (I checked using console.log) and they work just fine with catch().

Here is some code  :

```
 const keytar = require("keytar");
```

I am using it in a componentDidMount() function from react,

I tried these 2 versions but none of them seems to be working :

```
  keytar
  .setPassword("stoma", "user", user)
  .then(() => {
   console.log("User .. OK !");
   })
  .catch(() => {
   console.log("User .. ERROR !");
   ok = false;
   })
```

and

```
 keytar.setPassword("stoma", "statut", "true");
```

Here's some error log too :

```
 keytar.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: keytar.setPassword is not a function
at keytar.js:38
at keytar.js:12
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at callbackPromise (keytar.js:11)
at Object.setPassword (keytar.js:37)
at _callee$ (Login.js:52)
at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:288)
at Generator.prototype.(:3000/anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:1881:21)
at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
at asyncToGenerator.js:32
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at asyncToGenerator.js:21
at _validate (Login.js:48)
at validate (Login.js:48)
```

If some can help , I would be grateful.Thank you.

Comment: Set a couple [breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) on those lines of code. Maybe you're trying to use `keytar` before it's been defined. Or maybe your `require` is returning `undefined`. Perhaps that library register a global and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Do you have libsecret installed? Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Oops... you're using electron. See this for [debugging help](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electron/electron_debugging.htm).

Comment: JDP , I just said that the library is included and the functions are defined, Jimmy , I saw that libsecret but I didn't realy get how to install it, I am on windows but better have solutions for both OSs.

Comment: @Med-AmineBenyettou The library seems to have some external dependencies. Try to check if your Credential Vault is working properly on Windows. I didn't face any issues using keytar on Linux. I am using keytar 4.9.0 btw

Comment: @Jimmy I just checked and my Credential Vault is working just fine, from the documentation I don't see any other dependency that I need. But more importantly , can you confirm which code are you using in your .setPassword ? Thank you.

Comment: @Med-AmineBenyettou ```const keytar = require('keytar');

keytar.setPassword('service1', 'randoaccountid1', 'duck')
    .then(() => keytar.deletePassword('service1', 'randoaccountid1'))
    .then((status) => console.log(status))```

Comment: @Med-AmineBenyettou I know where your problem is. You are running keytar directly in Electron. You must run it in Node, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @Jimmy Yes that's right, but I don't realy get how to do it, my first time using electron. Should I use window.require("keytar") ? That gives me an error of unregistered plugin.. Thnaks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 1):

When using Electron, you have to use keytar through the main process. Calling keytar from the render process won't work.

As resolved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234059/packaging-keytar-with-an-electron-app) you have to do the following:

In the `main.js` file you have to define the listeners that you are going to invoke, with the keytar logic that you need. In this case, getting and setting the password

```
ipcMain.on('get-password', (event, user) => {
    event.returnValue = keytar.getPassword('ServiceName', user);
});

ipcMain.on('set-password', (event, user, pass) => {
    event.returnValue = keytar.replacePassword('ServiceName', user, pass);
});
```

Then from the renderer process, you can call

```
const password = ipcRenderer.sendSync('get-password', user);
```

or

```
ipcRenderer.sendSync('set-password', user, pass);
```

ipcMain docs: [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main). ipcRenderer docs: [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)